# Spring Cloud DataFlow using launch task after new file in AWS S3 Bucket source

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a batch processing started by a new file in AWS S3.

So the flow is:

```
1 - A new file is uploaded to AWS S3 Bucket
2 - SCDF detects
3 - SCDF launch the task (Spring Batch application)
4 - Spring Batch application process the file and stores in a DB.
```

Something similar to this, but with S3 Bucket:
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/batch/sftp-to-jdbc/

Maybe is a misunderstood of the concept, but in SFTP Source I could set Port, Host, User and Pass, but in S3 Source I doesn't have region and credentials properties.

Where do I set the AWS properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `Amazon AWS common options` section in the README (see: [old-app](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/aws-s3/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-s3/README.adoc#amazon-aws-common-options) / [new-app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/applications/source/s3-source#amazon-aws-common-options)), which includes the common AWS-specific properties one can override.

You can pass them as inline properties in the stream definition or when deploying the stream by following the deployer properties convention.

Answer (score 2):

I provided a detailed example of this use case [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/29/case-study-remote-file-ingest-with-spring-cloud-data-flow) (with Minio S3). This works out of the box with the latest release of stream applications, but will require some customization if you are using previous versions.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you attention. I was already following your use case, but I was having trouble with my bucket sync, if you could help me or give me some tip I appreciate a lot. I created another question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646098/problem-synchronizing-bucket-to-local-directory-with-spring-cloud-dataflow-str). Thank you again.